# Excel Type Provider has error - it needs an assembly "Excel.dll"

Tags: excel, f#, type-providers

So, I started with this code:

```
open System
open System.IO
open FSharpx
open Excel

module ExcelManipulation =

    type BoyICantWaitToUseThis = ExcelFile< @"C:\Users\sean.newham\Documents", "Sheet1", true>
    let example = new BoyICantWaitToUseThis()
```

...but it doesn't compile because I need an "Excel.dell, Version=2.1.0.0...", I didn't know which Excel.dll that was, so I tried including the [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/releases/view/100484), which has a dll called "Excel.dll", but alas, this does not appear to have removed the error message.

Any idea what I need here and where I could get it from?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have office installed? https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/issues/223

Comment: I do have office installed, but I can't find a dll with that name in office.

Comment: and I have added a reference to the Excel Data Reader @mydogisbox.

Comment: And that did/didn't work?

Comment: I added some more explicit information how exactly what you need to reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that until about 5 days ago (see [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/issues/223)), the excel type provider had a dependency on having Office installed with the office interop files.  The newer version depends on the Excel Data Reader.

If you look at the pull request for that change [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/pull/236/files), you see that the type provider used to reference

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx) for instructions on how to install that.

As an added bonus, you can look at the unit tests in that link for details on how to use the provider.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP but installing the PIA did not fix the issue... Where do I have to install the PIA files?

Comment: The installer should put them in the correct location.  Have you verified you have the right version installed?

Comment: Actually, the installer asks where the PIA should be installed. I am not sure where it goes or where I could point my environment to the location where I install the PIA.

Comment: I managed to get the PIA working referencing the COM `Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library`. Now I have the impression that the script works but InstelliSense still displays the same error `the type provider 'FSharpx.TypePorivder.ExcelProvider+ExcelProvider' reported an erro: Could not load file or assembly 'Excel, Version=2.1.0.0, ...`

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis Interesting

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at this same point trying to use FSharpx.TypeProviders.Excel. I switched to ExcelProvider and it worked out-of-the-nuget-box:

http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/